# Creating a custom module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a module that could potentially be used by several applications. I've seen several questions here about this subject and there doesn't really seem to be a standard approach. For my purposes, a module seems like the best bet.

I am injecting my module into my controllers where I want to use it, but I can't seem to expose the methods on the module. This is the relevant code from the module:

```
(function (ng) {
"use strict";
angular.module('oDataHelpers', [])

angular.module('oDataHelpers').value("oDataHelpers", oDataHelpers)


function oDataHelpers() {
    var module = this; 
    module.getKeyFromURL = getKeyFromURL;
    module.buildQueryString = buildQueryString;

    // assumes the last value on a URL represents a key value
    function getKeyFromURL() {
        return "myString";
    };


    function buildQueryString(container, propertyList, operators, fieldList) {
        return "my other string";
    };
    return ({module: getKeyFromURL, module: buildQueryString});
}
```

})(angular);

When I am running a method in one of my controllers I can see oDataHelpers in the debugger, but none of the methods and of course, when I try to call one of these methods, I receive an error indicating that the method is not a function. What am I missing?

Comment: there is an extra bracket at the end -> `}})(angular)` I guess this has nothing to do with it, but I don't dare to correct it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd post the relevant parts of what I ended up doing because I haven't really seen a solution elsewhere that seems to adhere to current best practices. This is largely based on @tcooc's answer and also a blog entry by Ben Nadel found here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2472-hashkeycopier---an-angularjs-utility-class-for-merging-cached-and-live-data.htm

(function (ng) {
    "use strict";

```
angular.module('oDataHelpers',[]).factory("oDataHelpers", oDataHelpers)

function oDataHelpers() {
    var module = this; 
    module.getKeyFromURL = getKeyFromURL;
    module.buildQueryString = buildQueryString;

    function getKeyFromURL() {
        return "string" ;
    };

    function buildQueryString(container, propertyList, operators, fieldList) {
            return "my string" ;
    };
    return module;
}

})(angular);
```

This is working perfectly for me and has no references to other parts of my app, so I'm free to use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're going in the right direction. First thing is, `value` provides a direct value, so referring to `oDataHelpers` will get you the function rather than the object. Your pattern is actually `factory`.

Another thing is that `angular.module(name, [])` *defines* a module, while `angular.module(name)` *loads* a module. So the second `angular.module` call is unnecessary.

Keeping those in mind (with some additional fixes):

```
(function (angular) {
"use strict";
angular.module('oDataHelpers', []).factory("oDataHelpers", function() {
    var module = {}; 
    module.getKeyFromURL = getKeyFromURL;
    module.buildQueryString = buildQueryString;

    // assumes the last value on a URL represents a key value
    function getKeyFromURL() {
        return "myString";
    };

    function buildQueryString(container, propertyList, operators, fieldList) {
        return "my other string";
    };
    return module;
});
})(angular);
```

Comment: nothing wrong with the angular module declaration...that part of answer seems misleading as it being a problem

Comment: @charlietfl Was clarifying the difference between declaring a module and getting a module (and that the second call is unnecessary). Clarified in the answer.

Comment: yeah...unnecessary sounds better

Comment: Thank you. Initially I had tried factory and didn't get very far. Not sure what changed between now and then, but simply changing value to factory and returning module did the trick. There's a lot of discussion on this topic and this approach looks much cleaner than the other solutions I've seen.

Answer (score -1):

First I would set this as  service or factory but should work regardless .

The `return` is wrong...you have duplicate property names in an object which is invalid but you don't need that object returned when the object that needs to be returned is already defined as `module`

Try:

```
return module;
```

Which would be the same as

```
return this;
```

As for creating an angular module for portability...that's what modularity is all about!

Comment: I had already tried both return this and return module; both of which I expected to work; both didn't.